# Delete logic for duplicate data is throwing ORA-00913: too many values

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-delete, ora-00913

I am trying to perform delete on a table containing Duplicate values using the SQL logic below but oracle is throwing ORA-00913: too many values error when executed.

```
DELETE
FROM
  UT_USER
WHERE
  ROWID NOT IN
  (
    SELECT
      MAX(ROWID),
      USER_NAME,
      MODULE,
      EFF_BEGIN_DT,
      EFF_END_DT,
      STATUS,
      EDW_CREATE_DATE_TIME,
      EDW_UPDATE_DATE_TIME,
      EDW_CREATED_BY,
      EDW_UPDATED_BY,
      EDW_UPDATE_NOTE
    FROM
      UT_USER
    GROUP BY
      USER_NAME,
      MODULE,
      EFF_BEGIN_DT,
      EFF_END_DT,
      STATUS,
      EDW_CREATE_DATE_TIME,
      EDW_UPDATE_DATE_TIME,
      EDW_CREATED_BY,
      EDW_UPDATED_BY,
      EDW_UPDATE_NOTE
  ) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SELECT` statement in your `NOT IN` returns a number of columns.  It has to return exactly one column to be valid (hence the error).  Fortunately, it looks like you can just eliminate the extra columns you are selecting

```
DELETE
FROM
  UT_USER
WHERE
  ROWID NOT IN
  (
    SELECT
      MAX(ROWID)
    FROM
      UT_USER
    GROUP BY
      USER_NAME,
      MODULE,
      EFF_BEGIN_DT,
      EFF_END_DT,
      STATUS,
      EDW_CREATE_DATE_TIME,
      EDW_UPDATE_DATE_TIME,
      EDW_CREATED_BY,
      EDW_UPDATED_BY,
      EDW_UPDATE_NOTE
  ) ;
```

Comment: Thank you, the above logic has worked. I initially thought that the number of columns used in the inner query must match with the outer query.